# Error in CMD because windows username has spaces in it

Tags: cmd

I tried running this command but it keeps showing the following error.

```bat
C:\Users\NIHARIKA CHATURVEDI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages> pyuic5 -x homepage.ui -o homepage.py
'C:/Users/NIHARIKA' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I think there's issue in my username.

I have also tried quoting arguments:

```bat
pyuic5 -x "homepage.ui" -o "me.py"
```

```bat
pyuic5 -x "C:\Users\NIHARIKA CHATURVEDI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\homepage.ui" -o "C:\Users\NIHARIKA CHATURVEDI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\me.py"
```

```bat
pyuic5 -x "%userprofile%\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\homepage.ui" -o "%userprofile%\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\me.py"
```

```bat
pyuic5 -x "%cd%\homepage.ui" -o "%cd%\me.py"
```

But none of these worked.

Comment: Have you tried with `%userprofile%`? Type `pyuic5 -x "%userprofile%\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\homepage.ui" -o %userprofile%\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\me.py"`. Or even with `%cd%`? Type `pyuic5 -x "%cd%\homepage.ui" -o "%cd%\me.py"`. What are you getting now?

Comment: Or try even quoting the files: `pyuic5 -x "homepage.ui" -o "me.py"`. Which of these ways worked for you? Also, please see [why I downvoted your question](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode).

Comment: The last paragraph on last help page output on running in a command prompt window `cmd /?` explains that a file name with a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` must be enclosed in `"` or the space character is interpreted as argument string separator. Please click on gray displayed __delete__ after using the command whatever it is (I can't read images, just text) with enclosing all file names in double quotes.

Comment: @double-beep I improved format of my question, can you remove the down vote or something more needs to be done?

Comment: Are you getting the same error? [Edit]  your question to clarify which is the error you are getting. Also, suggest to try `"C:\full\path\there\pyuic5.exe" -x "C:\Users\NIHARIKA CHATURVEDI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\homepage.ui" -o "C:\Users\NIHARIKA CHATURVEDI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\me.py"`. Is it working?

Answer (score 2):

You should enclose filenames in double-quotes:

> The completion code deals correctly with file names that contain spaces
> or other special characters by placing quotes around the matching path.
> Also, if you back up, then invoke completion from within a line, the
> text to the right of the cursor at the point completion was invoked is
> discarded.
>
> The special characters that require quotes are:
> `<space>`
>
> ```bat
> `&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`
> ```

<sup><sup>From `cmd /?` help page (last page)</sup></sup>

So, there are many posssible solutions:

**1.** Just **double**-quote filenames:

```bat
pyuic5 -x "homepage.ui" -o "me.py"
```

**2.** Include **double**-quoted **full path**:

```bat
pyuic5 -x "C:\Users\NIHARIKA CHATURVEDI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\homepage.ui" -o "C:\Users\NIHARIKA CHATURVEDI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\me.py"
```

**2.1** Using `%userprofile%` environment variable:

```bat
pyuic5 -x "%userprofile%\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\homepage.ui" -o "%userprofile%\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\me.py"
```

**2.2** Using `%cd%` environment variable to make it even shorter:

```bat
pyuic5 -x "%cd%\homepage.ui" -o "%cd%\me.py"
```

**Some clarifications**:

`%userprofile%` environment variable holds value `C:\Users\%username%` where `%username%` environment variable holds the name of the user currently logged in. Both variable values are unquoted.

`%cd%` holds the value of the path of the current working directory.

The error you were getting was because system understood `homepage.ui` and `me.py` as `C:\Users\NIHARIKA CHATURVEDI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\homepage.ui` and `C:\Users\NIHARIKA CHATURVEDI\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\me.py` respectively.

Suggest to read last page of help in `cmd /?` and this great answer by @dbenham:

[How does the Windows Command Interpreter (CMD.EXE) parse scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4094699/)

Answer (score 0):

**use "User name"**
I am installing mongodb server and faced the same error.

[image]

So just put double quote before and after user name.

Example :   C:\Users\"Prabhat Suman"\mongodb\bin
[image]